# TypeScript problem with type on returned value

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, typescript-typings

I'm getting this tslint error:

```
TS2322: Type 'ItemList | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Transaction<any, any, any>[]'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Transaction<any, any, any>[]'.
```

I have this code:

```
import { Transaction } from 'types';
import { DocumentClient as DynamoDBDocumentClient } from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';

export default async function getMyTransactions (
  _root: any,
  args: null,
): Promise<Array<Transaction<any, any, any>>> {

    //some code for query and other stuff

  const { Items } = await DocumentClient.getInstance().query(query).promise();
  console.log('Items', Items);

  return Items;
}
```

In the `console.log(Items)` I get something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: '123',
    commissions: {
      cc: 500,
      total: 1337
    },
    createdAt: '2001-02-03T04:05:06+07',
]
```

`Transaction` type is this one:

```
// I wont put the whole code, but those TF, TV, TC are used on other types not listed here
export interface Transaction<TF, TV, TC> {
  id: string;
  commissions: Commissions;
  createdAt: string;
}
```

So, in the beginning of my function I declare that it will return: `Promise<Array<Transaction<any, any, any>>>`

So `Items` is actually an array of `Transaction` type object.

Why I'm getting the error?

Comment: `Items` is whatever type that `await DocumentClient.getInstance().query(query).promise();` resolves to. The error would seem to indicate that is of type `ItemList | undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [typings](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/5ae5a7d7d24d1000dbc089cc15f8ed2c7b06c542/clients/dynamodb.d.ts#L1979) the `Items` property can be undefined, because you are using the `strict` setting in your `tsconfig.json` this will result in an error. So a simple fix is to always return an array:

```
export default async function getMyTransactions (
  _root: any,
  args: null,
): Promise<Array<Transaction<any, any, any>>> {
  // ...
  const { Items } = await DocumentClient.getInstance().query(query).promise();
 
  return Items || [];
}
```

Or you have to update your return typing to reflect what `Items` can be, and you should handle this undefined at the consumer of your method:

```
Promise<Array<Transaction<any, any, any>> | undefined>
```

---

Unfortunately the typings of dynamodb do not have any generics when you are querying the data. I can assume you will have to do the following to make it work:

```
export interface Transaction<TF, TV, TC> extends AttributeMap {
  id: string;
  commissions: Commissions;
  createdAt: string;
}
```

and perhaps you have to specifically type cast it, but not sure about that:

```
const { Items } = await DocumentClient.getInstance().query(query).promise();
 
return Items || [] as Transaction<any, any, any>[];
```

Comment: Hm, yes, I have `strict: true` in config. I tried both suggestions but now it gives me another error: https://i.imgur.com/0KiAlZZ.png

Comment: Last line did the trick, thanks! `Promise<Array<MyTransactionsResponse>>` and `return Items as Array<MyTransactionsResponse>;`